# Display "chapter" from the List of appendices

Tags: tocloft, minitoc, appendix

Can somenoe help me remove the "chapter' title from the list of appendices. I just want :

```
  LIST OF APPENDICES
 APPENDICE 1 : Questionnaire 1...........................
 APPENDICE 2 : Questionnaire 2............................

\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt, french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headheight=26pt, headsep=25pt, heightrounded]{geometry}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} %more common footnote style
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % footnote presentation
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % 
\graphicspath{{\images}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, hhline}
\usepackage[justification=centering, margin=2cm,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular, siunitx, lscape}
\newcounter{tabenum}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
 \usepackage{epigraph}
 \usepackage{xpatch}
 % page layout
 % page layout
 \usepackage[activate= {true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
 \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ANNEXES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \newcommand{\listappendixname}{Liste des annexes}
 \newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}
 \makeatletter
 \AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
 \clearpage
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LISTE DES ANNEXES}
 \write\@auxout{%
 \string\let\string\latex@tf@toc\string\tf@toc% 
 \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@apc% 

   }
 }
 \AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
 \write\@auxout{%
\string\let\string\tf@toc\string\latex@tf@toc% 
 }%
   }

 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \dominitoc
  \clearpage\shipout\null


 \listofappendix
 \clearpage
 \begin{appendices}
 \chapter{Questionnaire 1}
  \lipsum[4]
  \chapter{ Questionnaire 2}
  \lipsum[5]
  \end{appendices}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: It means you want to remove the text `Questionnaire 1` and `Questionnaire 2" from TOC?

Comment: @MadyYuvi In the TOC , I need " chapter 1, Chapter2....LIST OF APPENDICES" and actually I have the results with my code. My problem is with the list of appendices. I need to have in the toa "toc of appendices" just the name appendice 1, Appendice2......cause what I get is "Chapter A": Questionnaire...."Chapter B" : Questionnaire....I hope that I made myself clear Thank you